# Which authdata from google signin to use in authdata object sent to Parse Server with Swift 3 and iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server, google-plus-signin

I am using Swift 3 to allow users to sign into my app which utilizes a Parse-Server backend.  I can sign-in with Google Plus just fine, but I get an error when I send the authData to the Parse Server for token verification of the user, I get the general error, "Google auth invalid for this user."  I suspect I am sending the wrong "id" called for in the loginWithType method.  I examined the code in the Parse-Server repository and it just had "id" and "token" as its parameters.  I suspect I am sending the wrong "id".  So id need the proper information to send as the id parameter and a double check of my format.  Below is the code I am using.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    print("google sign in hit in app delegate")
    if (error == nil) {
        print("error is not nil")
        var curUser = PFUser.current()
        if (curUser != nil)
        {
            print("Skip Google Auth - Found cur user");
            return;
        } else {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID
            // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let fullName = user.profile.name
            let givenName = user.profile.givenName
            let familyName = user.profile.familyName
            let email = user.profile.email
            let idt = user.serverAuthCode


            PFUser.register(AuthDelegate(), forAuthType: "google")

            PFUser.logInWithAuthType(inBackground: "google", authData: ["id":user.authentication.clientID,"token":idToken!])
            // logging in confirmed on back end
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
authData: ["id":user.authentication.clientID,"token":idToken!]
```

to:

```
authData: ["id":userId!,"token":idToken!]
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error.  If you are sure this is the correct format, the problem must be in the implementation of parse-server.

Comment: I'm not. Can you print userId?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but in case you did not figure this one out you need to edit your authData keys to:

```
 let authData = ["access_token": access_token,
                        "id":id]
```